# Removing header from empty page without removing page numbering

Tags: header-footer, numbering, fancyhdr, page, emptypage

I'm using a two-sided openright report template for my thesis and I am trying to only remove the page header from the auto-generated empty pages (due to the even/odd page number interaction) and keep the page numbering. I have tried to include the *emptypage* package but to no avail, as it also removes the page numbering at the start of a new chapter. Down below is the code generating the page header and page numbering.

```
% Header and footer settings (Select TWOSIDE or ONESIDE layout below)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}} 


% Select one-sided (1) or two-sided (2) page numbering
\def\layout{2}  % Choose 1 for one-sided or 2 for two-sided layout
% Conditional expression based on the layout choice
\ifnum\layout=2 % Two-sided
    \fancyhf{}                                  
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{         % Redefine the plain page style
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} 
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\else           % One-sided     
    \fancyhf{}                  
    \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}` in the argument for fancy page style `plain`, if the page number should appear on chapter pages.

If the blank pages should use page style plain, you can load package `scrextend` with option `cleardoublepage=plain`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrextend}

% Header and footer settings (Select TWOSIDE or ONESIDE layout below)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                               
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\space#1}{}} 


% Select one-sided (1) or two-sided (2) page numbering
\def\layout{2}  % Choose 1 for one-sided or 2 for two-sided layout
% Conditional expression based on the layout choice
\ifnum\layout=2 % Two-sided
    \fancyhf{}                                  
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{         % Redefine the plain page style
      \fancyhf{}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
      \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    }
\else           % One-sided     
    \fancyhf{}                  
    \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now it works as intended, thank you so much!